# Creating Huffman Tree & Table Using a Heapsort

Tags: python, huffman-code, heapsort

Huffman Code Tree Exercise, Write a program with menu options that:

Asks the user for the name of a text file and then read the file, compute the relative frequencies of the 128 ascii characters and write this to a text file, one floating point frequency per line.

reads a text file containing 128 lines each with a floating point number that represents the relative frequency of the corresponding ascii symbol in a given text type. Each Line correspond to the ASCII code of that line number, so line 32 is equal to ASCII code 32.

Build a Huffman Code tree using the Assigned Frequencies from the file, ignore the ascii codes less than 32, ie only use lines 32-127.

Print the tree using the following algorithm:

```
def printTree("Tree", indent = ""):

#inorder Traversal

  if theres a right subtree:

    printTree("node.right",indent+" ")

  print(indent, data)#data is equal to a character and if no char, then is equal to a " * "

  if theres a left subtree:

    printTree("node.left",indent+" ")
```

Create and Print a Huffman Code table from the data. ( Similar to Below)
[image: Like So..]

That is what I'm attempting to do, however I've been able to build a tree (At least I think I have been able to, but I'm having trouble traversing the left or right children of the tree and building the corresponding byte code for the code table. I've made it this far but now I'm at a lost and I need some outside input to help trigger me in the right direction, and to ask questions or someone to report what I've done wrong, and help show me how I'm wrong.

```
def pushDown(H,i,n):
    #Allows larger values to be at top of tree

    while i <= n//2:
        lc = i*2
        rc = 2*i+1
        if H[lc] > H[i] and (lc == n or H[lc] >= H[rc]):
            H[i],H[lc] = H[lc],H[i]
            i = lc
        elif rc <= n and H[i] < H[rc]:
            H[i],H[rc] = H[rc],H[i]
            i = rc
        else:
            break

def Heapify(H):
    #Creates a tree

    n = len(H)-1
    for i in range(n//2,0,-1):
        pushDown(H,i,n)
    return H

def Hsort(H):
    #Sort into a heap

    Heapify(H)
    n = len(H)-1
    while n > 1:
        H[n], H[1] = H[1], H[n]
        n = n-1
        pushDown(H,1,n)
    return H

def heapify(array, n, i):
    highest = i
    l = (2 * i) + 1
    r = (2 * i) + 2

    if l < n and array[i] < array[l]:
        highest = l

    if r < n and array[highest] < array[r]:
        highest = r

    if highest != i:
        array[i],array[highest] = array[highest],array[i]

        heapify(array, n, highest)
    return array

def Hsort(array):
    n = len(array)
    while n > 1:
        for i in range(n, -1, -1):
            heapify(array,n, i)
        for j in range(n-1, 0, -1):
            array[j], array[0] = array[0], array[j]  
            heapify(array, j, 0)
        n -= 1
    return array
def hf(dic):
    d = [dic]
    d2 = []
    node = []
    left = []
    right =[]
    length = len(dic)
    lbits = {}
    rbits = {}
    for key, value in d[0].items():
        d2.append(value)
    for i in range(length):
        r = min(d2)
        node.append(r)
        d2.remove(r)
    while len(node) > 1:
        Node = node[0] + node[1]
        child = Hsort(list((node[0],node[1])))
        if node[0]:
            left.append(child[0])
        if node[1]:
            right.append(child[1])
        node.remove(node[0])
        node.remove(node[0])
        node.append(Node)
    for l in left:
        lbits[l] = 0
    for r in right:
        rbits[r] = 1
    print('lbits', lbits, '\nrbits', rbits)

def path(dic = None):
    if dic in [None, '']:
        print('No root, Error')
        raise KeyError
    else:
            hf(dic)

path()
##
##Input requires to loading from a file
##but Here are some frequencies that are in one of my test files.
0.05926
0.01025
0.01232
0.0336
0.09376
0.01824
0.01116
0.06372
0.04097
0.00055
0.00529
0.02724
0.01829
0.05085
0.05385
0.0093
0.00021
0.03707
0.04275
0.07018
0.01959
0.0071
0.01418
0.0006
0.01303
0.00082
```

I'm sorry ahead of time if this is poorly formatted, I'm tired and decently frustrated with this program.

Comment: some code is missing like `pushDown()` method (maybe more) can you provide the full code, also an input...

Comment: I fixed the lack of the pushDown(), um as for an Input I added frequencies but the issue is it's supposed to take a file and read the line # and assign the frequency which is a decimal like I added above to the corresponding ASCII code.

Comment: what is your desired output? can you show an example?